# Publish Asp.net web application to ftp

Tags: asp.net, webforms, publish

i want to publish my asp.net web application to my hosting. i am using the publish feature in visual studio 2013 ultimate. it is publishing correctly but the website is not opening i am getting could not load type error, i have tried many different configurations.

in the publish section i have choose : publish to ftp, fill in the correct information for the hosting and finally i used these configurations:

[image]

[this is the error i am getting[image: ][1]]

what can i do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

i have figure it out. the problem was i need to put the web.config in the root directorie